# Store multiple names and numbers in an array(?), retrieve and edit when needed

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am pretty new to objective-c, and I've tried searching around for possible answers - and I've had little to no luck.

What I want to do is store multiple names and numbers, and retrieve these when needed. It's basically for storing scores.

I tried using an NSDictionary, which contained keys and objects, where the keys were the names and object was the score. However, I am not sure how I can retrieve the number and add something onto it, as I am getting an incompatible pointer warning and the application breaks.

Is there a better approach to store user details and scores and retrieve them and update them when needed?

Comment: Can't you create a class UserScore with 2 properties (user and score) and create an array of UserScore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NSDictionary` seems like a okay start, since this searches more efficiently than an array. Maybe you get trapped by `NSNumber != int`. (NSNumbers are objects, no primitives.) Check [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/) and see, if they help you.

A simple example, assuming `dict` is actually a `NSMutableDictionary`,
notice the `@` when setting the new value:

```
int currentPoints = [[dict objectForKey:@"name"] intValue];
int newPoints = currentPoints + 5;
[dict setObject:@(newPoints) forKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: Thank you. I was missing the @ when setting the new value, which was creating a breakpoint in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Either create a mutable array of mutable dictionaries, or a mutable array of custom UserInfo objects.

Something simple like this would work:

```
@interface Userinfo: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name
@property (nonatomic, assign) int score

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store data like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];  
[dictionary setObject:@"player1" forKey:@"user_name"];
[dictionary setObject:@"10" forKey:@"user_score"];
[userList addObject:dictionary];
```

you can retrieve as mentioned below :

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[userList objectAtIndex:0]];
lblName.text = [dictionary valueForKey:@"user_name"];
lblScore.text = [dictionary valueForKey:@"user_score"];
```

I think this will work for you.